# 3.5 mm 4 pole cable works with headset and smartphone but not with laptop

Tags: windows-10, laptop, cable, headset

I recently got a 3.5mm 4 pole cable for my Turtle Beach Stealth 400 headset cause I lost the one it came with.

It works fine with the headset and my smartphone but it doesn't work with my laptop. What gives?

My laptop used Windows 10 if that helps

Comment: Please edit your question to add the model of laptop you are using. The fact it’s running Windows 10 shouldn’t be a factor.

Answer (score 1):

There are two standards for the 3.5mm 4 pole connectors with stereo + mic.

- OMTP starts with the left channel at the tip, then right channel, ground, and mic at the base.
- CTIA goes left, right, mic, ground

It's possible that you have purchased a cable that implements the opposite standard from whatever Turtle Beach provided. Many Android phones support the CTIA standard but it's also conceivable that your phone supports both if it worked with the old headset cable too.